# Lucene slow retrieving documents by ID

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I'm indexing data and I've noticed searches are taking a long time. I'm storing the content and file path for files.

```
document.add(new StringField(SearchField.FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH.getName(), fileData.getFilePath().toString(), Field.Store.YES));
document.add(new TextField(SearchField.CONTENT.getName(), fileData.getContent(), Field.Store.YES));
```

After the search has completed it loops through the document ids and retrieves the file path stored in a field. This loop takes a very long time.

```
final TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();

searcher.search(query, collector);

final TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, Math.max(1, collector.getTotalHits()));

final ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

final SearchResult[] result = new SearchResult[hits.length];

for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    final Document document = reader.document(hits[i].doc);
    result[i] = new SearchResult(Paths.get(document.get(SearchField.FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH.getName())));
}
```

I'm wondering if it is taking a long time to retrieve documents because it has to load all of the file content from the disk even though I don't access the `CONTENT` field. If this is the issue then I possibly would have to change the way the data is stored.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the content field is long, this is probably slowing things down.

Two solutions are available here:

1. If you never need to get the content from the index, you only need to search it, you should change this field to be unstored:

   ```
   document.add(new TextField(SearchField.CONTENT.getName(), fileData.getContent(), Field.Store.NO));
   ```

   That will reduce the size of result passed back from the index, and reduce the size of the index itself, as well.
2. If you *do* need the content field to be stored, but just don't need the contents of it for this call, you can pass in a `Set<String>` containing the field names for the fields you need returned from [`IndexReader.document`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#document-int-java.util.Set-)

   ```
   Set<String> getFields = Set.of({SearchField.FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH.getName()});
   for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
   {
       final Document document = reader.document(hits[i].doc, getFields);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I decided to go for your first solution. Works great thank you!